# Локальные unit тест для проверки корректности ресурсов. Как получить context?

Tags: android, android-studio, юнит-тесты

Есть некая игра и нужно проверить корректность данных хранящихся в ресурсах причем для каждой "локали" отдельно. Как мне представляется локальный тест отлично подходит для проверки на JVM.

Первый вопрос можно ли получить `context`, чтобы вытащить ресурсы?

Второй вопрос можно ли как-то узнать сколько "локалей" в приложении уже находится, скажем по наличию переведенной строки (values, values-de, values-ru и т.п.), чтобы потом сформировать массив суффиксов для доступа к папкам `assets`? Было бы идеально.

Сам такую задачу решил просто создав процедуру в приложении и выполнив ее на устройстве с "логированием" ошибок, но желательно все-таки проходить тест.